# Do most browsers automatically search for the favicon.ico?

Tags: html, favicon

I would like to know if it is necessary for me to specify it like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="[URL]" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="[URL]" type="image/x-icon" />
```

or can I just include it in the root and the browser will look for it?
Also what's the difference between  `rel="icon"` and `rel="shortcut"` ?

Comment: Why *not* specify it explicitly, though? What if your users are using an older browser that doesn't look? I'm not sure I understand what the *harm* is in being explicit.

Answer (score 26):

All of the major five browsers look in the site's root for a file named exactly `favicon.ico`, regardless of type, automatically.

You can override this with a `link` element with `rel="icon"`, or `rel="shortcut icon"`. The latter is supported by every browser, while the former is more correct, but not recognised by Internet Explorer.

Comment: Not necessarily true for mobile browsers as of 2023. I've just tested with Firefox on Android (`Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:109.0) Gecko/110.0 Firefox/110.0`), which did not make a request for `/favicon.ico`, whereas Firefox on desktop did.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers these days will look for a `favicon.ico` file on the root of the site.