# Will favicon.ico in the main directory appear in all sub-directories?

Tags: html, favicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do most browsers automatically search for the favicon.ico?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798689/do-most-browsers-automatically-search-for-the-favicon-ico)

Will a `favicon.ico` that is placed in the main directory appear in all sub-directories?

```
www.site.com         (favicon should show)
www.site.com/gallery (will favicon show here?)
```

Or does a `<link rel="icon">` need to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers will check for a favicon in the site root even if an explicit `link` is not present (eg. Firefox, Chrome and Opera all do, I'm fairly sure that IE will too but I'm not on a Windows machine at present).  You can test this by starting up a local webserver, requesting a page and looking at the resulting logs.

If you want to override the favicon in a sub-directory, or have a favicon at a location other than `/favicon.ico` then you need to use the `link` tag.

Comment: Works in IE. Actually, that was the first browser to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is should be only one favicon for one specific site. And it is should be placed in ONE place, where you want. But in every html use open the favicon tag must exists

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you put the favicon at the root it will show up in subdirectories as long as you put it in your `Head` tag.

Comment: I no longer include a link to the favicon in my HTML documents. As long as the icon is named favicon.ico then browsers will automatically find it.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the favicon.ico in the root directory and it will be placed in all the pages and directory no need to add it in all the pages