# Why is there a Favicon showing every time I make an index.html file and open in browser

Tags: html, favicon

Whenever I make an index.html file and write **Anything** inside it then open it in browser, I see a Favicon that I have never seen before. I want to know why is that Favicon showing and is there any way to stop it?, I didn't even add a html tag for a Favicon but It's still showing.

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>This is a title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Favicon**

[Image of Favicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhS0q.jpg)

Comment: Probably cache.

Comment: What browser? Do you have a favicon in your root directory?

Comment: I am using Chrome. I don't have any favicon in my root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all try to be sure that your project do not have favicon. Try to open www.[mysite].com/favicon.ico. If there is none pass to step two.
2. Wrong favicon could be taken automatically from your browsers cache. Try to hard reload your page (for mac it is shift+cmnd+r)
3. If favicon still shows and you do not want to show any favicon just pass empty href for it inside your header tag
   `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">`

Answer (score 0):

The major browsers look into the root folders after a "favicon.ico", you can find more info on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798722/14476782) (another Stackoverflow thread)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a webpage automatically makes an automatic favicon request on page load.
To prevent this add following to `head` of your HTML tag.

`<link rel="icon" href="data:,">`